Serialize empty yaml blocks
I have a use case where I want to be able to have a yaml node without any content. The problem recides in the conditions part in the following example:
name: test obj
properties:
  - name: Name
    type: string
    conditions:
      - not-empty:
  - name: temperature
    type: int
    conditions:
      - not-empty:
      - range:
        min: -10
        max: 40

In case of the not-empty condition I get an Exception because the not-empty property cannot be found in the c# class.
YamlDotNet.Core.YamlException: 'Property 'not-empty' not found on type 'pock_yaml.portfolio.properties.NotEmpty'.'

namespace pock_yaml.portfolio.properties
{
    public class NotEmpty : PropertyCondition
    {
    }
}

The same is also true for the range class where the ranger property does not exist.
The base class on the NotEmpty class is empty to, but is needed to figure out the type as described here.
For now I can work around it by adding the property like this
namespace pock_yaml.portfolio.properties
{
    public class NotEmpty : PropertyCondition
    {
        [YamlMember(Alias = "not-empty", ApplyNamingConventions = false)]
        public object? Empty { get; set; }
    }
}

but the value that it holds would never be read. Is there a way to go without it?
